# gsub different phrases of graphical characters

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a dataframe containing lines of characters for example:

```
hello my name is sam <U+ab93>
hi i love fast cars <U+e>
my favourite colour is yellow <U+E><U+c><U+60>
```

How would I remove all the terms that don't make sense in this dataframe?

I tried `apply(document, 1, function(x) gsub("<[:graph:]>", "", x))` but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using gsub

```
text = c("hello my name is sam <U+ab93>" , "hi i love fast cars <U+e>" , 
"my favourite colour is yellow <U+E><U+c><U+60>")

df <- data.frame(DOC = text)

df$DOC <- gsub(df$DOC , pattern =  "<.*>", replacement = "")
```

Comment: I don't think perl=TRUE is needed here

Comment: But, it is almost similar to @Avinash Raj's answer

Comment: yeah but it uses simpler regex

Comment: I haven't tested to check if this fails in some cases.

Comment: this is a very simple regex that matches optional characters between `<` and `>`

Comment: And also this is greedy. check your regex with `<foo> bar <buzz>`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yeah that's a good catch , I tried to make regex that fits texts given in example , but your point is totally right

Comment: You could just add `?` in order to make it not greedy, such as `"<.*?>"`

Answer (score 3):

For

```
document = c("hello my name is sam <U+ab93>", 
             "hi i love fast cars <U+e>", 
             "my favourite colour is yellow <U+E><U+c><U+60>")
```

It would be,

```
gsub("<[[:graph:]]+>", "", document )
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xO9iG4/2)

`[:graph:]` not a valid POSIX char class.

---

Alternatively, you could also try

```
gsub("<[^>]*>", "", document)
```